# Filtering a collection of tags-based huge strings with AND, OR, *

Tags: c#, string, filter

I'm stuck at something that looks easy... but that is apparently not.

We've got a "big" (3000 records and counting) collection of words (issued from résumés) stored in a database : one record per candidate, one string property with every word separated by a space.
one of my colleague asks me if it's possible for him to write search strings like "A" AND ("B" or "C*") AND ("D" OR ("E* AND *F"))
when he asked it it looked easy, but I'm stuck on this, not even knowing where to start. from what I've gathered already by looking online, well... it occured to me I've been the only human being with this particular need.
I've read that it looked like I needed tree-like filters, but id someone had a bit of code to get me started, that would be greatly appreciated ;)
if you know a c# library that does it, that would be perfection.

I guess I could migrate my bdd to store each word in a separate table w/foreign keys if it could be of any help...

thanks anyway !

Comment: You want to do this with a database query or in an application?

Comment: In that logic does `"C*"` mean anything that starts with C?  I mean you could convert that to SQL `columnOfWords like '% A %'` (assuming you put a space at the beginning and the end of the column) would match if the word "A" exists then `like '% C%'` would handle words starting with "C", but this could be a very inefficient query.  You might want to look into full text search solutions.

Comment: in a database query.
ideally on the server side, just by sending the query string and parsing it.
yeah the C* starts with. and when you mention "full text search solutions", you mean... paid ones ? I haven't really looked for those, as I wnated to search for libraries first. I'll look into this.

Comment: to be more specific, it's an asp.net website made with visual studio, EF code first, sql server. I've got complete control as I'm the only developer on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally used Lucene.Net, as it has everything I need already implemented as is.

thanks for your answers.